# Retrieve salted MD5 password on login PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5, salt

I've been searching around and I can't find the answer to what I think should have been logical. I will include the sections of code that are used to insert upon registration (and proper validation) and that used to select in hopes you have ideas.

On the registration page I insert the password as an MD5 of the concatenation of a random unique salt and the user desired password. (I am open to suggestions to improve this if this is not sufficient to store passwords).

```
$InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO login (firstname, lastname, username, password, salt, activation) VALUES ('$fnamePost', '$lnamePost', '$usernamePost', MD5('$salt$passwordPost'), '$salt','1')";
```

On the login page I have the following code to check the password:

```
    $saltQuery = "SELECT * FROM login where username = '$username'";
$saltResult = mysql_query($saltQuery);
$saltArray = mysql_fetch_array($saltResult);
$saltPass = $saltArray['salt'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username' AND password =   MD5('$saltPass$password')";


if($result1 = mysql_query($query)) {
    if($success1 = mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
```

At this "success1" point it returns zero rows meaning incorrect username and password.

Printing the query itself I appear to get an MD5(saltpassword) search, but this does NOT match the password stored in the table.

What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance.

**Addition** : So, the problem is between what the register page says the password is and the select query on the login page is trying to match.

Example: Register password: 5586ef3ede51ef5b41676801d6870574  -- Login Password: f90dacb09ffd1cbf4bdf13b3175da696

This means that somewhere between adding the salt and the MD5 we are getting differing results.

Comment: It would help if you can print your show create table login output. Also, the select * from login output, of at least a single row that is suspect.

Comment: md5 is no longer a good idea

Comment: @Geremy Table Create Table 
login CREATE TABLE `login` (
 `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `FirstName` text NOT NULL,
 `LastName` text NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `salt` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 `Activation` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Have you checked whether the content of `$saltPass` matches the salt associated with the username in the database?

Comment: @Sutandionodi yes the $saltPass does match the associated username

Comment: MD5 is not suitable for password storage. The fact that you're trying to use it is a strong indicator that you shouldn't be trying to do this yourself. Consider use an off-the-shelf library, this stuff is *hard* to get right and you are almost certainly going to get it wrong.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `echo $InsertQuery;` from register page and `echo $query;` from login page?

Comment: @Sutandiono sure, the echo $query shows :  `SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = 'g@dell.com' AND password = '0fe6ff6dc0d418ad263263f84580322f'` and the echo of $InsertQuery shows: `INSERT INTO login (firstname, lastname, username, password, salt, activation) VALUES ('test', 'tasasdf', 'g@dell.com', 'a85f571bd256b798ecd3669527f47347', '52f46dd808f40944662966','1')
`

Comment: I will try to troubleshoot this, off first glance the salt is longer than what I am letting the table add,  so I will make this adjustment and see if that works.

Comment: The above was the problem... to respond to @meagar - this is not a response to my question. For the purposes I am using this database and information accessible from it, a unique 23 character salt concatenated with a user password and with an MD5 hash is more than enough security. Granted, the method of maintaining the salt is not the most secure way as it is not "random" and I am aware a random function generator is the way to go. I do thank you for the comment as others will likely view this post and get some valuable information from it.

Comment: @Dm3k1 No, that's miserably bad security. MD5 is not for password hashing. And I know that is isn't an response to your question, it was helpful advice, that's why it was a comment and not an answer. I will say it again: You are doing this wrong, and exposing yourself to huge trouble down the road. MD5 is, for password security purposes, a dead algorithm. The fact that you think storing a plaintext salt next to the hashed password somehow saves you just makes it that much more obvious that you should be using somebody else's battle-tested library to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this line is working ok?

`$InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO login (firstname, lastname, username, password, salt, activation) VALUES ('$fnamePost', '$lnamePost', '$usernamePost', MD5('$salt$passwordPost'), '$salt','1')";`

Because you put the MD5 function into a string.. I don't think that it'll fix your problem, but have you tried something like

`$variable = md5($salt$passwordPost)` then insert `$variable` in the query?

Comment: It works because OP put the content of `$InsertQuery` in double quotes, so the variables `$salt` and `$passwordPost` are expanded correctly before concatenated in the `MD5()` call.

Comment: @user3260711 Yes, it does concatenate $salt and $passwordPost into an MD5. Can the problem be my unique salt is based on the pre-defined uniqid() function that is stored as $salt which is time based and when it stores to the table as 'salt' it has changed values? My understanding of how things work is that once the query starts the value $salt has been defined and thus this should be impossible?

Comment: I should add, if I manually change the pw to just MD5(password) in PhpMyAdmin and remove the $saltPass prefix from the select query I log in no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I had limited my salt to 12 characters on the table but specified it to be longer. Thus, the password field was a concat between the longer version of the salt and the user inputted password, the salt however only being the first 12 characters of the unique id.

Thank you for your help.